# how to do Bulk download of all files from azure blob as zip folder (We should not use Azure storage explorer)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob

Azure blob - **Bulk download of all files (It could be images/videos) as zip folder programatically/any other azure features. (We should not use Azure storage explorer)**

We have tried azure data factory - we could achieve 90%, but we should trigger event to client once zip folder is downloaded. In azure data factory, we could not trigger event.

Please suggest any other solution approach if someone accomplished this activity.

Comment: Using C#, it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches, I followed the below approach and it worked for me.

**Approach 1**

Uploaded the files to the container.

[image]

Using the below code downloaded all the files from container and converted into a zip folder.

```
string storageAccount_connectionString ="ConnectionString";
CloudStorageAccount mycloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = mycloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(azure_ContainerName);

     var blobs = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();
     foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
      {
           string fileName = blob.Name;
           CloudBlockBlob blobFile = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
           blobFile.DownloadToFile(@"C:\Tools\Files\" + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
       }
       Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
       string sourceFilePath= @"C:\Tools\Files\", path = @"C:\New folder";
       string startPath = sourceFilePath;
       string zipPath = path + @"\result.zip";
       ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
```

All blobs to a zip

[image]

**Approach 2** is [StreamSaver approach](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com)

Comment: hi Rajesh, thank you, i will check this solution and update here.